# How to display data from text file into many columns?

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I have text file which consists of many rows and 18 columns of data seperated by tabs. I used this code and it is displaying entire data in single column. What I need is the data should be displayed in columns.

```
public static List<string> ReadDelimitedFile(string docPath)
{
    var sepList = new List<string>();           

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(docPath))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            var delimiters = new char[] { '\t' };
            var segments = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (var segment in segments)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(segment);
                sepList.Add(segment);
            }

        }

        file.Close();
    }
    // Suspend the screen.
    Console.ReadLine();
    return sepList;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use some object/collection that supports columns such as a DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting everything in one column like this (pseudo-code, to illustrate structure):

```
while (reading lines)
  for (reading entries)
    WriteLine(entry)
```

That is, for every line in the file and for every entry in that line, you output a new line.  Instead, you want to only write a new line for every line in the file, and write the entries with separators (tabs?).  Something more like this:

```
while (reading lines)
  for (reading entries)
    Write(entry)
  WriteLine(newline)
```

That way all the entries for any given line in the file are on the same line in the output.

How you delimit those entries in the output is up to you, of course.  And to write a carriage return could be as simple as `Console.WriteLine(string.Empty)`, though I bet there are lots of other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

18 columns would seem to be served best by using a dataGridView.

```
 //  Create your dataGrodView with the 18 columns using your designer.

        int col = 0;
        foreach (var segment in segments)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(segment);
            //sepList.Add(segment);

            dataGridView1.Rows[whateverRow].Cells[col].Value = segment;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `DataTable` or similar type for that but if you want to use `List` you can "emulate" rows and columns like this:

```
var rows = new List<List<string>>();
foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines(docPath))
{
    var columns = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    rows.Add(columns);
}
```

That will give you row/column like structure

```
foreach(var row in rows)
{
    foreach(var column in row)
    {
       Console.Write(column + ",");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So according to your code, you have a following loop:

```
while{
   <reads the lines one by one>
   for each line{
       <reading each segment and adding to the list.>
   }
}
```

Your code read each segment of a line and append to the list. Ideally you should have 18 list for 18 columns. In java this problem can be solved with hashmaps:

```
Hashmap <String, ArrayList<String>> hmp = new Hashmap<String, ArrayList<String>>();`

while(read each line){
    List<String> newList =  new ArrayList<String>
    foreach(segment as segments){
        newList.add(segment);
    }
    hmp.put(column1,segment); 
}
return hmp;
```

so you will have `hmp.put(column2, segment)`, `hmp.put(column3, segment)`  and so on.

Hope it helps.